# Abcéder ou s'abcéder ?

Tags: vocabulaire

J'ai lu dans le Larousse 2016 le mot *s'abcéder*, alors que selon le [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abc%C3%A9der) cette forme n'est pas correcte, *abcéder* n'est pas un verbe pronominal. Que faut-il dire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le TLFi condamne ? Je nuance : il rapporte les propos de grammairiens qui condamnèrent l’usage pronominal, tout en mentionnant que Bescherelle l’approuva en 1845, et que cette approbation ne fait que ratifier **un usage déjà ancien**, et ce en dépit du fait que ce choix s’inscrive contre l’étymologie.

Je réorganise un peu une section de l’article du TLFi pour mettre en évidence la démarche de réflexion suivie, et je fais remarquer que très tôt dans les exemples, le TLFi emploie la forme *« s’abcéder »* *(le centre du nodule se ramollit, **s'abcède**)*  :

> La forme pronominale, **étymologiquement impossible**, est **passée dans l'usage** aux XVIIIe et XIXe siècles, mais est condamnée dans toute la lexicographie, excepté dans Bescherelle 1845 qui ratifie l'usage :
>   • Il paraît par ces passages [tirés de l'œuvre d'un chirurgien] qu'un bon oculiste n'est pas pour cela un bon grammairien. —Trév. 1752.
>   • On trouve quelquefois dans les livres de médecine *s'abcéder*, comme si *abcéder* est un verbe réfléchi, C'est une faute, abcéder est un verbe neutre, et on ne peut pas plus dire s'abcéder que se procéder. —Littré.
>   • C'est à tort que l'Académie, M. Landais et tous les dictionnaires ne mentionnent pas l'emploi du verbe abcéder avec le pron. personnel. On le trouve ainsi employé dans les écrivains spéciaux. La tumeur s'abcède. (Saint-Yves) (...) Cette phrase suffit pour démontrer que *abcéder* n'est pas seulement un verbe neutre, comme l'indiquent tous les dictionnaires, mais qu'il peut aussi s'employer pronominalement. —Besch. 1845.

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe *abcéder* est très peu utilisé.

Par analogie avec la plupart des verbes employés dans un contexte similaire, il me semble très difficile d'éviter la forme pronominale :

- s'irriter
- s'infecter
- s'enflammer
- se nécroser
- se gangrener
- se contracter
- se dilater
- s'ulcérer
- se tuméfier
- ...